# How to make anonymous block work

Tags: oracle, plsql, block

Let's say I have this ksh :

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s u/p <<EOF
  WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 98;
  WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;

  set heading on
  set feedback on
  set echo on
  set pagesize 0

  SELECT field1 FROM MY.TABLE;
EOF
```

The select is made : it is okay

Now let's add an anonymous block around the query :

```
DECLARE
    VARIABLE VARCHAR2(2) := 99
BEGIN
    prompt before select
    SELECT field1 INTO VARIABLE FROM MY.TABLE;
    prompt after select
    EXIT NUMCARSAT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        prompt NO_DATA_FOUND
        EXIT 99;
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        prompt TOO_MANY_ROWS
        EXIT 99;
END;
```

The query is not executed anymore. Why is that ?

Comment: in a PLSQL block you can not do SELECT ... FROM..., but you need an INTO: select ... INTO ... FROM ...

Comment: Please read the basics of PLSQL here. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_basic_syntax.htm

Comment: ok.. I am going to change my code.. because I put the minimum code but it is not exactly what I am doing

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can simply run your query:

```
SQL> select 1 from dual;

         1
----------
         1
```

But within a PLSQL block, you need to use your query to build a cursor, do a loop, fetch data into some variable, ...

For example:

```
SQL> begin
  2    select 1 from dual;
  3  end;
  4  /
  select 1 from dual;
  *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement


SQL> declare
  2    a number;
  3  begin
  4    select 1 into a from dual;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you used is not used in oracle plsql. The right syntax is as below:

```
DECLARE
    VAR VARCHAR2(2) := 99 ;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('before select');

    SELECT field1 
     INTO VAR 
     FROM MY.TABLE;

    --dbms_output.put_line is used to print to console
    dbms_output.put_line('before select');
    dbms_output.put_line('value ='||var);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('NO_DATA_FOUND');
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
         dbms_output.put_line('TOO_MANY_ROWS ');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot use the "prompt" statement within a PL/SQL block, so your syntax is invalid.

Second, you need to append a single slash on a separate line after the DECLARE/BEGIN/END PL/SQL block, or else SQL*Plus will wait for more input, like this:

```
BEGIN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('none of this will be parsed until slash below appears on standard input');
END;
/
```